# JDBC Connection Pool failed for SQLServer

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, connection, edit, ping

I was making a connection from JDBC Connection Pool to SQL Server but an error has occurred:

> Ping Connection Pool failed for SQLServer. Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : com.ddtek.jdbcx.sqlserver.SQLServerDataSource Please check the server.log for more details.

[image]

Comment: According to the error you don't have `com.ddtek.jdbcx.sqlserver.SQLServerDataSource` on the classpath of the application server itself. BTW: Why aren't you using the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver?

Answer (score 0):

1. Download JDBC driver for SQL Server
2. Copy the JDBC driver for database connectivity (JAR) to as-install/domains/domain_name/lib/ext